# Axios Post Request Giving Reference Error

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm having trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong here. I'm making a simple axios post request in nodeJS. I'm receiving `ReferenceError: btoa is not defined` regardless of what I include as the data. Included is the entire js file. The error points to the following axios code `requestHeaders.Authorization = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);`. So I'm thinking it has something to do with my auth code in the post request.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const btoa = require('btoa');
const base64 = require('base-64');
const axios = require('axios');
const express = require('express');
const Xsolla = require('xsolla').default;
const client = new Xsolla({
    merchantId: 137852,
    apiKey: '41235123663432asdf',
})
const router = express.Router();

var data1 = JSON.stringify({
  "user": {
    "id": {
      "value": "user_2"
    },
    "name": {
      "value": "John Smith"
    },
    "email": {
      "value": "john.smith@mail.com"
    },
    "country": {
      "value": "US",
      "allow_modify": true
    }
  }
      
const axios = require('axios');
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://api.xsolla.com/merchant/v2/merchants/137852/token',
  headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           },
  data: data1,
  auth: {
    username: '137852',
    password: '4lsjfwlJfslfJ'
  },
})
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The error is not here. Can you share the whole code

Comment: @DheerendraDev I included the entire file, thank you.

Comment: @vthree123 I can't see the  code where you've used btoa. Can you re-check the snippet in the question. I can't find the header where you're setting Authorization.

Comment: @SriramR If you refresh you should be able to see the authorization set. I can see it on my end if you scroll a bit down, thank you.